# database file is locked" when chrome browser is running

Tags: java, sqlite, browser-history

My goal is to get chrome history, this works fine. But my problem is getting "The database file is locked" only when chrome browser is running.
How can I fix this problem?
Can I stop database chrome browser?
this my code:
    public class GetChromeHistory
    {
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {

```
Connection connection= null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
Statement statement = null;

try 
    {

    // We think, but are not sure, that the line below registers the sqlite drive with JDBC.
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      connection = DriverManager
        .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:db.db");
    statement = connection.createStatement();

    //problem occurs on line below, database file is locked
    resultSet = statement
        .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM urls where visit_count > 0");


    while(resultSet.next()) 
        {

        //eventually save into a set or list 
        System.out.println ("URL [" + resultSet.getString("url") + "]" +
                    ", visit count [" + resultSet.getString("visit_count") + "]");
        }
    }   

catch(Exception e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } 

finally 
    {
    try 
        {
        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
        } 

    catch(Exception e) 
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you share your code here?

Comment: @RicardoPontual you can view it now.Have you any solution plz?